is clockwork framework obsolete?
CONTEXT:
In existing solana playground https://beta.solpg.io/tutorials/bank-simulator anchor example the framework clockwork is used. However, the example does not work because clockwork-sdk does not support latest versions of solana and anchor. Furthermore the clockwork projet looks abandoned - the last update was 9 months ago.
QUESTIONS:

Is there any framework that can be used instead of clockwork?
Is there any process of making the example work as expected?
Many thanks
Vlad


I can only answer question 1.
An alternative built by the community exists and here is the repo https://github.com/AdrenaFoundation/sablier

There is a fork called open clockwork maintained by https://x.com/tuanpmhd that was updated to some newer anchor version. Last time i checked a few months back it also still had some workers running on main and devnet. Doesnt look like its actively maintained though.
https://github.com/open-clockwork/clockwork
